# Erro no Xampp 3.22

Tags: xampp

Olá, eu uso o Xampp há mais de 1 ano e nunca tive nenhum problema com o mesmo, porém hj tive de formatar meu desktop e reinstalei uma versão mais nova do Xampp, a 3.22, ao iniciar o mesmo ele apresentou um erro:

[image: erro no xampp]

Já fiz o tutorial da pergunta [erro no xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly) e não funcionou, eu coloquei a porta 12344 no Skype. Alguma ideia?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perdão pela minha falta de atenção, não sabia que o gerenciador de tarefas mostrava esse 'PID' mas ao abrir o gerenciador não mostra esse processo com PID 3632, como pode ver no print, e eu abri o XAMPP para testar se funcionava e ele deu o mesmo erro, PID 3632.

O Sistema operacional é Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: Qual versão do windows?

Comment: Dá um `CTRL+SHIFT+ESC`, e vê qual processo é esse pelo PID. Vários programas, muitos mesmo e não só Skype, podem usar essas portas. Ninguém tem bola de cristal.

Comment: O problema é por que já está utilizando a porta 80 e 443  por outro serviço. Faça como o @DarkHyundrA mencionou para descobrir qual programa está impedindo o apache do XAMPP ligar

Comment: O sistema é Windows 7 Ultimate. Tentei olhar no gerenciador de tarefas o PID 3632 mas n aparece esse PID, veja o print acima por favor.

Comment: Mude a porta então para 8080 por exemplo, basta editar no arquivo httpd

Comment: Para saber o real erro, execute o apache pela linha de comando, abra o prompt de comando(iniciar>executar e digite cmd) lá entra na pasta onde está instalado o apache, algo como `C:\xampp\apache\bin` e digite `httpd.exe` e de enter, coloque a mensagem de erro na pergunta como texto e não uma imagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro é devido a porta 80 e a 443 que já está sendo usada.

- Abra o arquivo httpd.conf no bloco de notas e altere a linha **listen 80** para outra porta, por exemplo: **listen 8080**
- Após alterar a porta 80, abra o arquivo httpd-ssl.conf no bloco de notas procure pela linha **listen 443** e altere a porta 443 por outra.

Espero ter ajudado.